# Regarding multiple insertion of rows through single query.(oracle)

Tags: database, oracle10g

Is the mechanism used in multiple insertion of rows in the table through single query is same as that of inserting single row with a single query.If not what is the exact mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fetching the data from an existing table, you can use `INSERT INTO TABLE3 ( SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE2 ....)` to fetch and insert the data in a single go.

---

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = 'ANALYST1';

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO GENDER
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
      8909 LUTHAR     ANALYST1        7698 22-JUL-99       1232        788         50 F
      8999 AMAN       ANALYST1        7698 22-JUL-99       8569        788         50 M
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST1        7566 19-APR-87       3000        150            M
      7902 2          ANALYST1        7566 03-DEC-81       3000                       M


SQL> SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = 'MANAGER';

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO GENDER
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7566 5          MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975        150            F
      7698 10000      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850        150            F
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450        150            F
```

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EMP1 AS ( SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE 1=2);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM EMP1;

no rows selected
```

---

```
SQL> INSERT INTO EMP1 ( SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = 'ANALYST1'
  2  UNION
  3  SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP WHERE JOB = 'MANAGER');

7 rows created.
```

---

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMP1;
     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO GENDER
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
      7566 5          MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975        150            F
      7698 10000      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850        150            F
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450        150            F
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST1        7566 19-APR-87       3000        150            M
      7902 2          ANALYST1        7566 03-DEC-81       3000                       M
      8909 LUTHAR     ANALYST1        7698 22-JUL-99       1232        788         50 F
      8999 AMAN       ANALYST1        7698 22-JUL-99       8569        788         50 M

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: @Sathya....i tried ds method it works...thnx. I saw one method of pivot and unpivot insert.Could u explain me why we are using IN clause in that?

Comment: @Nitish - please ask a separate question on that. Also - click on the checkbox if this answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain many SQL statements in a single Oracle query by separating each SQL command with a semicolon.  For instance:
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1,2); INSERT INTO table VALUES(3,4);

Comment: No, they would be seperate sql statements. You should delete this answer before someone down votes you.